# I need some help debugging a calculation command

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I am trying to make a calculation but I have a few bugs and I do not understand them/how to fix them. Below is my syntax, the output, and the error messages. I am trying to calculate the point in my plot (done successfully in another window) where the areas are equal. I appreciate any help/advice.

```
p[v_]:=(8*.95)/(3*v-1)-3/v^2
Plot[p[v],{v,.5,3},PlotRange->{{0,4},
{.5,1}},
AxesLabel->{"v","p"},
PlotLabel->"van der Waals Isotherm for T/T_c=0.95"]
g[v_]:=-(.95)Log[3v-1]+.95/(3v-1)-9/(4v)
ParametricPlot[{p[v],g[v]},{v,.5,2.5},
AxesLabel->{"p","G/NkT_c"},
PlotLabel->"Gibbs free energy"]
pInt[v_]:=(8/3)*.95*Log[3*v-1]+3/v;
AreaDiff[p0_,v1guess_,v2guess_]:=(v1=FindRoot[p[v]==p0,{v,v1guess}][[1,2]];
v2=FindRoot[p[v]==p0,{v,v2guess}][[1,2]];
pInt[v2]-pInt[v1]-p0*(v2-v1));
FindRoot[AreaDiff[p0,.7,2]==0,{p0,.8,.82}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Define it with `p0_?NumericQ`. Seehttps://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037

Comment: What is the definition of the function `p`?

Comment: @BobHanlon p[v_]:=(8*.95)/(3*v-1)-3/v^2

Comment: It's best to add the missing code to the question, rather than leave it in the stream of comments.

Comment: Edit your question to include copy and pasteable code (`InputForm`). Include all code necessary to produce results (i.e., include that definition of p`).

Comment: @BobHanlon I added it and included the plots to incase.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Module[]` in the definition of `AreaDiff[]`. Also, `p0_?NumericQ` and similar for other variables. See the code below.

```
p[v_] := (8*.95)/(3*v - 1) - 3/v^2
Plot[p[v], {v, .5, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {.5, 1}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"v", "p"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "van der Waals Isotherm for T/T_c=0.95"]
g[v_] := -(.95) Log[3 v - 1] + .95/(3 v - 1) - 9/(4 v)
ParametricPlot[{p[v], g[v]}, {v, .5, 2.5}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"p", "G/NkT_c"}, PlotLabel -> "Gibbs free energy"]
pInt[v_] := (8/3)*.95*Log[3*v - 1] + 3/v;
AreaDiff[p0_?NumericQ, v1guess_?NumericQ, v2guess_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{v1, v2}, (v1 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v1guess}][[1, 2]];
    v2 = FindRoot[p[v] == p0, {v, v2guess}][[1, 2]];
    pInt[v2] - pInt[v1] - p0*(v2 - v1))];
FindRoot[AreaDiff[p0, .7, 2] == 0, {p0, .8, .82}]
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hey, @mszynisz thanks for your reply. I fixed the syntax and I still get an error message. COuld it be an issue with my software?

Comment: What's the error message? Remember to clear all the variables before running my code.

Comment: adding image to original question

Comment: Close Mathematica completely, open a clean notebook, and run the code?

Comment: @DwightShelford, mszynisz -- probably forgot `ClearAll[AreaDiff];` before defining the function `AreaDiff`. I always start every definition of every function with this. Saves headaches.